# Simple ruby script to change file extension in a directory

Tags: ruby, rename

Could someone help me finishing this script to rename all  *.htm files to *.html in a given directory? Many thanks.

```
Dir.METHOD("*.htm").each do |html_file|
 FileUtils.METHOD html_file, "#{html_file.METHOD(/REGEX/,'.html')}"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Dir.glob` and select the `*.htm` files, then rename their extension name from `htm` to `html`:

```
Dir.glob('*.htm').each { |file| File.rename(file, file.sub('htm', 'html')) }
```

Although also exists [`rename`](http://plasmasturm.org/code/rename/):

```
$ rename 's/htm/html/g' *
```